# HTML completion with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Is it possible to use an Ajax response to fill in an html file ?

By example my Ajax response is :

```
<table>
    <tr><td>Patient : </td><td>Me</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Surgery date : </td><td>A date</td></tr>
</table>
```

How can I fill my html with that ?

I'm trying this but it doesn't work

```
...
<div class="test"> </div>
...
function search(lastname_patient)
{           
    $.post("../functions/ajax/search.php",
    {
      lastname_patient: lastname_patient,
    },
    function(data)
    {   
        $('.test').val(data);           
    });             
}
```

Comment: `$('.test').html(data)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `html` instead of `val`. This is same as `innerHTML` in Javascript.

```
$('.test').html(data);
//         ^^^^
```

> Set the HTML contents of the matched elements.

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/html/

Answer (score 1):

use jQuery .html()

```
function search(lastname_patient)
{           
    $.post("../functions/ajax/search.php",
    {
      lastname_patient: lastname_patient,
    },
    function(data)
    {   
        $('.test').html(data);           
    });             
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There ways to do it , You can do it like :

```
1. $(".test").html(data);

2. $(".test").replaceWith(data); - Dom element will be replaced too ,that .test class
```

Comment: what will happen next time `search` is called if using 2nd approach?